# Como usar o operator= para copiar um vector de ponteiros?

Tags: c++, classes, operadores

Tendo esta classe, gostaria de implementar, operador =, copiar o vector de ponteiros para int para outro vector, 
é obrigatoriamente necessário reservar memória antes de o fazer?

Qual é mesmo a diferença entre fazer um construtor por cópia e implementar o operador atribuição ? Construtor por cópia faz apenas uma cópia do objecto, enquanto operador de atribuição muda o conteúdo (neste caso)?

```
class ints{
private:
  vector <int*> inteiros;
public: 
  ints & operator=(const ints & i1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como usar o operator= para copiar um vector de ponteiros?

O `operador =` já é definido para `vector<int*>`

> é obrigatoriamente necessário reservar memória antes de o fazer?

Não. A alocação de memória pelo `std::vector` é automática. Não confunda, porém, memória para os ponteiros com a memória para os inteiros para os quais os ponteiros apontam. Quero dizer que, se você copiar um vetor de ponteiros para outro, ambos vão apontar para os mesmos inteiros.

> Qual é mesmo a diferença entre fazer um construtor por cópia e implementar o operador atribuição ? Construtor por cópia faz apenas uma cópia do objecto, enquanto operador de atribuição muda o conteúdo (neste caso)?

São coisas diferentes. Um é construtor e gera um objeto novo; Outro é um operador que opera num objeto já existente.

Geralmente, espera-se que quando um objeto é criado como cópia de outro o resultado sejam objetos iguais. Ou seja, após criarmos `B` da forma `Objeto B(A)`, esperamos que `B==A`

Geralmente, espera-se que quando um objeto é atribuído a outro, o resultado sejam objetos iguais. Ou seja, após aplicarmos `B=A`, espera-se que `B==A`

Perceba que costuma-se esperar o mesmo resultado através das duas operações, mas são coisas diferentes e você pode implementar cada um como queira.

Espero que o exemplo abaixo seja elucidativo, perceba que não crio nem o operador de atribuição nem o construtor. Deixo que o compilador os gere automaticamente:

```
class ints
{
public:
  //vetor de ponteiros para int
  std::vector<int*> inteiros;
  //função que imprime valor de todos inteiros apontados
  void escreve()
  {
    for(auto i:inteiros)
      std::cout << *i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Criando um objeto `ints A` e salvando no vetor deste alguns ponteiros:

```
//declara 3 ints
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int z = 3;
//cria objeto A da classe ints
ints A;
//salva ponteiros em A 
A.inteiros.push_back(&x);
A.inteiros.push_back(&y);
A.inteiros.push_back(&z);
```

Criando-se um objeto através de cópia de `A`:

```
//cria objeto B através de cópia
ints B(A);
```

Criando-se um objeto e usando atribuição para igualá-lo à `A`:

```
//cria objeto C e usa operador atribuição
ints C;
C = A;
```

Mandando imprimir os conteúdos, verifica-se que os objetos apontam para os mesmos inteiros `x`, `y` e `z` declarados inicialmente:

```
//verifica conteúdo
A.escreve();
B.escreve();
C.escreve();
```

(resultado no terminal)

```
1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3,
```

Todos objetos contém vetores que apontam para os mesmos inteiros, ou seja, o valor dos ponteiros salvos nos vetores foram todos copiados de `A`. Pode-se verificar isso alterando o valor de algum dos inteiros apontados:

```
//A, B e C apontam para os mesmos inteiros, incluindo y
y = 666;
//verifica-se que a mudança é visível através de todos objetos:
A.escreve();
B.escreve();
C.escreve();
```

(resultado no terminal)

```
1, 666, 3, 
1, 666, 3, 
1, 666, 3,
```

[Aqui está o exemplo acima online.](http://ideone.com/rw3XtR)

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente classes que tem ponteiros como membros precisam implementar 3 métodos: copy constructor, assignment e destructor.

Pode ser necessário também implementar os métodos "move constructor" e "move assignment", mas é mais raro (este é um recurso novo que entrou no C++11).

Abaixo um exemplo que implementa os 3 primeiros métodos citados.

Esta implementação não trata os casos exóticos de copy constructor e assignment onde os dois operandos são o mesmo (p. ex.: " x = x").

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class IntVector
{
   public:
      vector<int*> elements;

      // default constructor   
      IntVector() { cout << "\ndefault constructor\n\n"; }

      // destructor
     ~IntVector() { cout << "\ndestructor\n"; clear(); }

      // copy constructor   
      IntVector(const IntVector& src);

      // assignment
      IntVector& operator=(const IntVector& src);

      // adiciona um elemento
      void add(int i) { elements.push_back(new int(i)); }

      // libera elementos   
     void clear();

      // imprime elementos   
      void print(const string& msg);

private:

      // copia elementos   
      void copy(const IntVector& src);
};

void IntVector::clear()
{
   cout << "liberando memoria\n";

   for (auto ptr : elements)
       delete ptr;

   elements.clear();
}

void IntVector::copy(const IntVector& src)
{
   cout << "copiando elementos\n";

   for (auto srcP : src.elements)
   {
      // cria um ponteiro e inicializa com o valor correspondente
      int* newP(new int(*srcP));
      elements.push_back(newP);
   }
}

// copy constructor
IntVector::IntVector(const IntVector& src)
{
   cout << "\ncopy constructor\n";
   copy(src);
}

// assignment
IntVector& IntVector::operator=(const IntVector& src)
{
   cout << "assignment\n";

   // libera os elementos atuais
   clear();

   // copia novos elementos
   copy(src);
}

void IntVector::print(const string& msg)
{
   cout << msg <<": [";

   for (auto p : elements)
       cout << " " << *p;

   cout << "]\n";
}


int main()
{
   // default constructor
   IntVector v1;

   v1.add(1);
   v1.add(2);
   v1.add(3);
   v1.add(4);
   v1.add(5);

   v1.print("v1");

   // copy constructor
   IntVector v2 { v1 };
   v2.print("v2");

   IntVector v3;

   // assignment
   v3 = v1;  
   v3.print("v3");
}
```

Veja funcionando em http://ideone.com/jJVwJd.

Comment: Acho que entendi o reforço que você quis dar na manipulação de memória dinâmica, mas se cada ponteiro do vetor é dono do inteiro que aponta, porque não usar direto um `vector<int>`?

Comment: estou me atendo ao contexto da pergunta....além disso, procurei ser didático: classes que possuem ponteiros como membros normalmente precisam de constructor, copy constructor e destructor...além disso, a partir do C++11 não se aconselha usar "naked pointers", e sim "unique_ptr" e "shared_ptr"